Why are Functions within sha-256 picked with certain exact magic numbers?
SHA-256, as described in its original paper, contains certain specific functions such as Σ1(X) = RotR(X, 2) ⊕ RotR(X, 13) ⊕ RotR(X, 22)
or Σ1(X) = RotR(X, 6) ⊕ RotR(X, 11) ⊕ RotR(X, 25) Why are the values for the amount of right shifts exactly the way there are (e.G: for Σ1(X), why not pick 3, 14, 23?)
Is there some cryptographic reason for this, or is this an arbritrary choice?

Welcome to crypto.SE. Please format the question using MathJAX so community can better understand it. Here is the reference guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

SHA-256 is SHA-2 and NIST has a long way of experience with/without SHA-0, and SHA-1's errors. This knowledge is on their site as long as there is no proof.
